# Assert more than one JMeter variable in Xpath Assertion

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I have a textfield whose DOM is as follows

```
<input type="text" name="txtCurrentCashTally" id="txtCurrentCashTally" CLASS ="protected" disabled="disabled" value="0" size="20" maxlength="13">
```

Now I have
xpath: `//input[@id='txtCurrentCashTally']/@value='0'` to match this field.
I want to assert if this xpath contains a value which is a variable that I use.

Var_A is the xpath `//input[@id='txtCurrentCashTally']/@value` from Xpath Extractor on the response.
Var_B is from another response.

Using Xpath assertion, is it possible to assert if Var_A = Var_B?

I can try out the "JMeter Variable name to use" but is there a way to pass multiple variable names there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just replace this `0` with `${Var_B}` and you should be good to go:

[image]

If you want to compare 2 JMeter Variables it can be done with [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion):

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)

Answer (score 0):

After you got the 2 variables use [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and assert them using:

```
 AssertionResult.setFailure(!vars.get("Var_A").equals(vars.get("Var_B")))
```